# How to integrate paypal payment in flutter

Tags: paypal, flutter

I want to integrate PayPal payments in my flutter app but that functionality does not exist. I chose to use a flutter webview to load an html file that integrated the PayPal JavaScript SDK.

When I click on the PayPal button nothing happens. I think it's because the flutter Webview can't open another page for the payment process.

How can I bypass that problem?

Answer (score 0):

With the plugin `Flutter LiquidCore`(https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_liquidcore) you can execute `Node.js` or `JavaScript` code within a virtual machine. Have a look at it, maybe it's just a `WebView` bug

Comment: Thanks, i will try it and come to you.

Comment: i bypass the problem for android by integrating it with platform channel.

Comment: @kouadiofigux what do you mean? did you use in-app purchases?